# TYPO3 v6: How to include a custom user table?

Tags: typo3

Disclaimer: I am quite new to the CMS & Typo3 world, so if there are any points that I'm missing, please feel free to edit.

I want to import content from an already existing database to make it manageable by Typo3: perform searches using search form, and (ultimately) edit it through Typo3 backend modules.

From my current state of research, Typo3's standard content is stored into "tt_content", and to add other tables, it is necessary to play with the so-called $TCA array (see [Typo3 TCA reference](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/WhatIsTca/Structure/Index.html))

Fortunately, the so-called Kickstarter extension would help us create an extension including the $TCA and SQL definitions of the table. Unfortunately, it is not compatible with version 6.0. See [list of known incompatible extensions](http://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3_6.0_Incompatible_Extensions_K). Also, Kickstarter was not updated since v6 release.

How to create such an extension in Typo3 6.0? Why is it so hard to manage custom content? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kickstarter was used to create old school extensions for years anyway since few years there is new way for creating extensions - Extbase. It uses MVC pattern and is based on FLOW3 philosophy so it will be in use for long years ahead.

Use newest version of "Extension Builder" from repository to 'kickstart' your own Extbase ext

**Edit** You'll need to spent some time to learn how it works (especially repositories and models), preferably create some easy extension with small amount of fields and try to recognize how its structure looks like, you'll get familiar fast.

Then use Builder's '*sheet view*' to '*draw*' the structure of your current table. If you'll do it carefully you'll be able to import existing data almost without problems. There will be probably some differences, however that's easier than doing that from the scratch.

Comment: So, I understand that building extensions is the recommended way to include custom content. I tried Extension Builder, but the Model-View interface bugs me... Thank you anyway!